# why the font-family are in two place in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just saw in Bootstrap that its using font-family in two places one in `html` and another in `body`:

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

...and after many lines:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

So, why is `font-family` used in two places with the different font?

Comment: I think `html` is a fallback isn't it? So if for whatever reason a browser can't render `Helvetica` or anything in the `body` font stack then fallback to the default `sans-serif` font. I haven't researched this but it's what I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set of styles defined in Bootstrap.css is actually [Normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css). Noramlize.css makes up the [first 189 lines](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L189) of Bootstrap.css.

If we take a look at the unminified version the full code snippet with comments is actually:

```css
/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Why is it defined twice? Because they bundle Normalize.css without modifying that CSS file that defines a `font-family` for the `html` element itself.

Normalize.css simply does it to set the base font to sans-serif. Their CSS file with comments states:

```css
/**
 * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevent iOS and IE text size adjust after device orientation change,
 *    without disabling user zoom.
 */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is now built using LESS. This means that the CSS is built in using variables and various different files which can sometimes overlap or have values set in different places.

First, it uses `normalize.less` which will make sure everything is set back to a base standard.

Line 1 - 13

```css
/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

//
// 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
// 2. Prevent iOS and IE text size adjust after device orientation change,
//    without disabling user zoom.
//

html {
  font-family: sans-serif; // 1
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; // 2
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; // 2
}
```

The body is then set within the `scaffolding.less` file which sets all the basics for bootstrap to use.

Line 26 - 33

```css
body {
  font-family: @font-family-base;
  font-size: @font-size-base;
  line-height: @line-height-base;
  color: @text-color;
  background-color: @body-bg;
}
```

This also happens within the SASS compiler too.

- [Github - Bootstrap Less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less)
- [Github - Bootstrap Sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets/stylesheets)

Answer (score 0):

After going inside the bootstrap LESS it is really easy to understand.

Its not a rule or workaround just a library colliding.

The `html {}` comes from the `normalize.css` inside bootstrap.

The `body {}` comes from the bootstrap itself.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Bootstrap uses a reset stylesheet (probably packed together with bootstrap into one minified version). The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on.

In this case the font-family reset is redundant because Boostrap changes the font right away on the body. Removing all redundant reset CSS would be a lot of work compared to very little gain.